# Make android app expire after 30 days

Tags: android

I need to implement an app that user can only use it before some date, example: 31/12/2017. I think I will implement it on onResume() function of every activity to prevent user run the app in the memory and never kill it.

Currently, I have 6 activities, add code to each activity is acceptable, but when an application becomes larger, this way is very stupid. How can I improve it?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to check date online. Otherwise user can change the date of phone locally, and your app will be unable to check whether it is real time..

Comment: @emiraslan thanks for advice, but actually I need to ask about implement it on onResume() function of every activity or just only MainActivity

Comment: @NhânTrần please check my answer. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For checking duration as you mentioned one month, I strongly suggest to adopt approach of online. I mean you need to have web service that verifies that expiry else user may fool you user can change device date and time locally and he will be keep using. And for your second question

```
Currently, I have 6 activities, add code to each activity is acceptable, but when an application becomes larger, this way is very stupid. How can I improve it?
```

No, you don't need implement in every activity that can be a bad approach inn future app extension as more activities are going to be added. You can do below steps

```
1) Create a BaseActivity 
2) Your every activity should extend BaseActivity
3) In onResume() method of your BaseActivity, check validity stuff of app user
```

Since BaseActivity is always a super Class that means every time your activity's onResume calls, onResume() will call its super class onResume. I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The following sets `isExpired` as of 12/31/2014:

```
GregorianCalendar expDate = new GregorianCalendar( 2013, 11, 31 ); // midnight
GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();

boolean isExpired = now.after( expDate );
```

Note: Months are 0-based. January = 0, December = 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.
Do this in your `splash activity` or `MainActivity`

```
private final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String installDate = preferences.getString("InstallDate", null);
    if(installDate == null) {
        // First run, so save the current date
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateString = formatter.format(now);
        editor.putString("InstallDate", dateString);
        // Commit the edits!
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        // This is not the 1st run, check install date
        Date before = (Date)formatter.parse(installDate);
        Date now = new Date();
        long diff = now.getTime() - before.getTime();
        long days = diff / ONE_DAY;
        if(days > 30) { // More than 30 days?
             // Expired !!!
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Do I need to implement on every activity? To prevent user run my app in memory before it expires, and reload from memory.

Comment: no Just implement on Splash or in your landing activity , then kill the application if time expires. or you can do in application class as well , just depend on your requirement

Comment: @quick learner what if the user clears the app data from settings? It will clear the preferences ,I think one must store the app date and installed date in web server

Comment: thaats up to your requirement and you can also save it in file in external directory , also hit api to save data on webserver .

Comment: look at this also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html